# Sorting a list of dates

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, date

I'm trying to sort a list of given type on the basis of the date

```
data = [('Anil Kumar', '18-08-2001'), ('Ajay Shastri', '18-08-2000'), ('Sumita Singh', '12-11-1885'), ('Rajni Patel', '11-01-1886'), ('Arshad Khan', '12-11-1887'), ('Christopher Diaz', '19-11-2005'), ('Abha Reddy', '01-01-2005')]
```

For that I am using `map` and `lambda` function

```
for k in range(len(data)):

         finaldata = list(sorted(data[k][1], key=lambda d: map(int, d.split('-'))))
```

But I am getting this error

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'map' and 'map'`

Comment: `lambda d: list(map(int, d.split('-')))` but the remainder of your code seems out of whack as well?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Sorry, but I'm not getting your question

Comment: your code is faulty in other ways as well - f.e. the `for k in range(len(data))` does not make any sense and `sorted(data[k][1],...) `  would sort the tuple ('Anil Kumar', '18-08-2001') - not the full list etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since `map()` returns an *iterator*, you cannot use it like that in a comparison function, since you cannot do equality comparisons with two `map` objects. Even if you cast to a `list` or another collection, there are still many other problems with your code, as highlighted in [@Patrick Artner's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732055/sorting-a-list-of-dates/62732262#comment110935338_62732055) comment.

Instead you should use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the date strings to datetime objects for the comparison `key` function.

The time format `"%d-%m-%Y"` is good enough here, where `%d` is zero padded days, `%m` is zero padded months, and `%Y` is years with century numbers included. You can refer to the [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) from the documentation for further reading.

**Demo**

```
from datetime import datetime

data = [('Anil Kumar', '18-08-2001'), ('Ajay Shastri', '18-08-2000'), ('Sumita Singh', '12-11-1885'), ('Rajni Patel', '11-01-1886'), ('Arshad Khan', '12-11-1887'), ('Christopher Diaz', '19-11-2005'), ('Abha Reddy', '01-01-2005')]

print(sorted(data, key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d[1], "%d-%m-%Y")))
```

**Output:**

```
[('Sumita Singh', '12-11-1885'), ('Rajni Patel', '11-01-1886'), ('Arshad Khan', '12-11-1887'), ('Ajay Shastri', '18-08-2000'), ('Anil Kumar', '18-08-2001'), ('Abha Reddy', '01-01-2005'), ('Christopher Diaz', '19-11-2005')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but is there no other way to do this sort without using datetime ?

Answer (score 1):

Converting dates to datetimes would be the preferred way to do this, but you can also use number sorting or lexicographical sorting:

```
data = [('Anil Kumar', '18-08-2001'), ('Ajay Shastri', '18-08-2000'), 
        ('Sumita Singh', '12-11-1885'), ('Rajni Patel', '11-01-1886'), 
        ('Arshad Khan', '12-11-1887'), ('Christopher Diaz', '19-11-2005'), 
        ('Abha Reddy', '01-01-2005')]

# integer sorting
finaldata = sorted(data, key=lambda d: list(reversed(list(map(int, d[1].split('-')))))) 

# lexicograph sorting
finaldata = sorted(data, key=lambda d: list(reversed(d[1].split('-')))) 

print(finaldata)
```

to get:

```
[('Sumita Singh', '12-11-1885'), ('Rajni Patel', '11-01-1886'), 
 ('Arshad Khan', '12-11-1887'), ('Ajay Shastri', '18-08-2000'), 
 ('Anil Kumar', '18-08-2001'), ('Abha Reddy', '01-01-2005'), 
 ('Christopher Diaz', '19-11-2005')]
```

To additionall sort by the name you need to sort with a key of `(date,name)`,
you can do this using:

```
finaldata = sorted(data, 
                   key = lambda d: (list(reversed(list(map(int, d[1].split('-'))))), 
                                    d[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Can you please elaborate "lexicographical sorting" and the sorting line of the code also, it'd be very helpful.

Comment: @gR see edit. Lexicographical works on the strings - if you split and reverse them, you sort by ["2000","10","4"] which works as well as sorting by [2000,10,4] - at least if your code padds months so you sort "03" before "10".

Comment: How can I sort it in alphabetical order also so that if new entry for eg (Aaman Singh, 01-01-2005) is appended, it should be placed at 5th index, as of right now it is placing this new entry at 6th index.